# How to schedule list of events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance

I need to schedule list of ~1000 events for a day, where every event is updating little component with just some text and a button.

Schedule events list example:

```
[
  {time: '00:00:00', updateString: 'foo'},
  {time: '00:03:15', updateString: 'bar'},
  ...
  {time: '23:57:49', updateString: 'baz'},
]
```

Will using a `setTimeout()` function in a loop affect performance negatively?
I mean, just adding ~1000 timers in the beginning of the day,
wouldn't it freeze the app?

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what are you asking for... can you give some example?

Comment: @Camilo, updated my question with the sample

Comment: Note that questions should be objective, so I've edited your question to remove subjective requests ("Best way", "Is it a good idea") and replaced them with things that can be answered objectively ("How", "Will it affect performance negatively"). It still needs a better example, code-wise. Generally, you want to avoid `setTimeout` in React programming, instead wrapping with promises or observables, or using memoization to distribute the load more evenly.

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to achieve, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 1000 timers are much of a problem.
I would *start* to worry about performance with 10k or 100k timers (which might still be no problem).

Anyway, setting many timers seems not optimal to me.

I think you could just keep your list in the state, and check regularly if one of the times is reached or exceeded (like `Date.now() > item.time`).

(Also note that a `setTimeout(f, 1000)` is not *guaranteed* to run after 1000 ms.)

If you need (kind of) milliseconds precision and a very long list, you could optimize by starting some mechanism only if a event time comes nearer than the main-check-interval. Maybe store a smaller list of *due-soon*-items.

E.g. check the list every 10 seconds, if some event is due in less than 10 seconds, then check just this item (or a subset of items) every millisecond.

Comment: thank you, @kca, and what about app going background state and back? Is it safe for the  `setTimeout` timers?